# link for umd-ros-pkg expired. Please update

Tags: ros, gps-umd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fuerte ubuntu 12.04

Unable to download the gps_umd package from umd-ros-pkg

sai@sai:~$ git clone git://ram.umd.edu/ros/gps_umd.git

Cloning into 'gps_umd'...
fatal: unable to connect to ram.umd.edu:
ram.umd.edu: Name or service not known

sai@sai:~$

I think the repository location is changed.
Please let me know from where the gps_umd package can be downloaded.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43488/link-for-umd-ros-pkg-expired.-please-update/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2012-09-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like their server is just down, I would suggest contacting the maintainers directly to notify them if they don't already know.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-09-10**:
Thanks.How to contact the maintainers?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have always had to use http://ram.umd.edu/git/ros/gps_umd.git as the `uri` for that repository, despite what the wiki page says.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2012-09-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-09-10**:
Yeah, but ram.umd.edu is just down entirely at the moment.

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-09-10**:
now its working..just tried it out..Thanks

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2012-09-11**:
Does the git:// prefix work for you? Or do you have to use the http:// prefix?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-09-11**:
first type "    roscd   " then "   git clone http://ram.umd.edu/git/ros/gps_umd.git  "This would clone the gps_umd stack into your ROS Workspace.